# get detailed user information in wso2 IS, RESTful api

Tags: soap, oauth-2.0, wso2, openid, wso2-identity-server

All,

I have configured wso2 to work with AD, So far i am able to

1. authenticate user using oauth2 api (/oauth2/token) using grant type password
2. fetch some basic user details using userinfo api(/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid)

I have created a new claim under "http:// wso2.org/claims" with name `distinguishedName` and `Roles`, So in console users list i am able to see users getting fetched with details from AD i can also see my new claimAttribute been added as part of user profile in userlist

So the problem is with point 2, when fetching basic user details i am getting data in following format, where `distinguishedName` and `Roles` attribute is not present

```
{
  "sub": "MM.COM/user3@carbon.super",
  "name": "user3",
  "preferred_username": "user3",
  "given_name": "user3"
}
```

I then refered following links
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/JWT+Token+Generation https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/OAuth2+Token+Validation

As said in above links, i am able to fetch some user details using OAuthTokenValidation SOAP service and i am able to get `distinguishedName` and `Roles` with some more information, that was good.
In fact for me SOAP based method is a secondary option here, i want to see if i am able to do same using RESTful /userinfo api.

Do any one have any idea, am i missing something?

Thanks. !!

Comment: Try claim configurations for the service provider. You should be able to get the required claims with local claim dialect. More information at this documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Claims+for+a+Service+Provider

Answer (score 0):

In the following registry location, under the properties section, there is a property called "openid". There, you have to add the relevant claim which you need to display. Please refer the attached screenshot(openid_location.png) for further clarification.

> /_system/config/oidc

[openid_location.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oslnm.png)